# how to get the digraph key or unicode from a special character

Tags: vim, unicode

I am configuring tmux & powerline. I would like to change the default separators in tmux status line. I managed to figure out where to do it, however I could not get the special character that I want.

I want to type, in Vim, a left/right pointing triangle that spans the whole line-height, but the only thing I could find is a small triangle (unicode : 25B6,25BA,25C0,25C4...)

There is a big right pointing triangle already in a powerline configuration file, which I could copy and paste, but I want to know its unicode and want a left one. Is there a way to get the unicode from the symbol in Vim or anywhere else?

Comment: with the ga command in Vim, I figured out the unicode of the solid right pointing triangle to be : e0b0, and then went from this, found out left solid triangle is e0b2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the codepoint value of a character in Vim by positioning the cursor on the character in question and typing either `ga` or `:ascii`.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `ga` in command mode or `:ascii` on the command line (even though it says ascii, it shows information for general encodings)

Answer (score 1):

You may add a permanent preview of current character in your status line (see :h statusline), eg.:

> :let &statusline = &statusline . "\ [%03b\ 0x%B]"